# Variables don't pass between nested functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a web scraper that need cookies and headers. I defined a function that returns them and I made a main function to run everything. But it doesn't get the cookies. When I run it with  `if __ name__ ==  __main:` it works but if I put it in a function it doesn't.

That doesn't work:

```py
def main(user, password):
    cookies, headers = login(user, password)
    for thread in argv[1::]:
        for photo in get_photos(thread):
            download(photo)
```

That does work:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cookies, headers = login(user, password)
    for thread in argv[1::]:
        for photo in get_photos(thread):
            download(photo)
```

Comment: In the non-working version, did you ever actually call `main()`?

Comment: @jasonharper ofcourse I did then it gave cookie not defined error.

Comment: Could not find an IndentationError.

Comment: @EnesDoğan if you are getting that error, you need to provide a [mcve]. really, you always should provide that, otherwise, we cna only speculate, since none of this would do anything except throw an error (or simply define a function)